# Control may reach end of non-void function switch statement

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

I tried to do a simple calculator. Don't understand why i'm getting the warning that "Control may reach end of non-void function." for the f() function. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f(int a, int b, int i){
    switch(i){
        case 1: return a+b;
        case 2: return a-b;
        case 3: return a*b;
        case 4: return a/b;
        case 5: return a%b;
    }
}

int main(){
    char Continue='y';
    int a,b,i;
    cout<<"1.Add"<<endl<<"2.Subtract"<<endl<<"3.Multiply"<<endl<<"4.Divide"<<endl<<"5.modulus"<<endl;
do{
    cout<<"Enter two numbers:"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter the number of what kind of caculation you want to do";
    cin>>i;
    cout<<f(a,b,i);
    cout<<"Press y to continue/n";
    cin>>Continue;
    }while(Continue=='y');
}
```

Comment: What will happen if i=6? Look into the the use of `default` in a switch statement.

Comment: It is also fun if `i` is `4` or `5` and `b` is 0.

Comment: Get those break statements in, for each case except default. This is very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Because if `i` is neither 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then the execution passes over the entire `switch` statement completely, and there is no explicit `return` from a function that should return an `int`.

Comment: I added an if statement to constrict the value of i within 1-5, or it'll cout "invalid". I don't understand the part you mentioned " there is no explicit return from a function that should return an int". Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: And it's still missing a return statement. Do you understand that you need to return something, from the function, in all cases?

Comment: I added "return 0" at the end of the f function, now the error's gone. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some type of default label into your switch statement, general syntax is as follows

```
switch(value)
{
case 0 :
//do something
break;
case 1:
break;
//// add any case as needed
default : // this would be the line you're missing
break;
}
```

non void means it doesn't return anything, it's the same thing as witting a function that returns a something, but instead you skip that part entirely

tldr you're esentially doing this

```
int non_void()
{
//do stuff but not return anything
}
```